# Why is CGWarpMouseCursorPosition causing a delay? If it is not, what is?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, core-graphics, mouse

I have code here that restricts the mouse to a region on the screen, it is working relatively well, with only one big problem. The mouse doesn't get moved cleanly/smoothly when running along the edges of the area, it instead jumps in a very choppy manner, I believe this might be due to CGWarpMouseCursorPosition causing a delay upon each "warp".

**Can anyone tell if it's something in my code that is causing this delay, or if it is in fact the mouse warp function. If it is the mouse warp function, is there any way I can get a smooth relocation of the mouse?** I've done the same thing in flash and it works flawlessly, I know that the loop isn't just taking so much time to execute that it's slowing things down because it only runs maybe 4 or 5 times.

```
CGEventRef 
mouse_filter(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void *refcon) {


    CGPoint point = CGEventGetLocation(event);

    float tX = point.x;
    float tY = point.y;

    if( tX <= 700 && tX >= 500 && tY <= 800 && tY >= 200){
        // target is inside O.K. area, do nothing
    }else{

    CGPoint target; 

    //point inside restricted region:
    float iX = 600; // inside x
    float iY = 500; // inside y

    // delta to midpoint between iX,iY and tX,tY
    float dX;
    float dY;

    float accuracy = .5; //accuracy to loop until reached

    do {
        dX = (tX-iX)/2;
        dY = (tY-iY)/2;

        if((tX-dX) <= 700 && (tX-dX) >= 500 && (tY-dY) <= 800 && (tY-dY) >= 200){
            iX += dX;
            iY += dY;
        } else {
            tX -= dX;
            tY -= dY;
        }

    } while (abs(dX)>accuracy || abs(dY)>accuracy);

        target = CGPointMake(roundf(tX), roundf(tY));
        CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(target);

    }



    return event;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoopSource;
    CGEventMask event_mask;
    event_mask = CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventMouseMoved) | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventLeftMouseDragged) | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventRightMouseDragged) | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventOtherMouseDragged);

    CFMachPortRef eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGHIDEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, 0, event_mask, mouse_filter, NULL);

    if (!eventTap) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't create event tap!");
        exit(1);
    }

    runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0);

    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);

    CGEventTapEnable(eventTap, true);

    CFRunLoopRun();

    CFRelease(eventTap);
    CFRelease(runLoopSource);
    [pool release];

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's slow; timing it, the longest I got it to take was 0.006 seconds. It could be better in a couple of ways, though: You should define the delimited region in an NS- or CGRect, and I do think you can cut out the loop.

Comment: The rectangle is just a temporary demo tool. I am actually going to be testing this against a black and white bitmap, where black pixels zones are mouse-friendly, and white zones the mouse cannot move into. The shape of the black area will be pretty bizarre, and thus I think the loop may be necessary. Unless you have a better solution?

Comment: That might actually make it easier to find whether the mouse has gone outside the acceptable area. The trick would be finding the nearest acceptable point to move it back to, but yeah, I think you will need a loop for that. Anyway, I'm surprised simply modifying the location and delta of the event (or even modifying and returning a copy) doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, apparently modifying the location of the event can't move the mouse cursor, that would have been too simple. I am thinking for determining the closest acceptable point to move the cursor to, an approach using a bit of trigonometry to project lines would work, but that would require some kind of intense algorithm to test every point on every line until it found the edge of the region... That seems too resource intensive since there could be something like 200 lines that would have each have to have as many as 200 pixels checked for black/white....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you discovered, `CGSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval` fixes your problem.

However, it's deprecated as of 10.6. the Apple docs state:

> This function is not recommended for general use because of undocumented special cases and undesirable side effects. The recommended replacement for this function is `CGEventSourceSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval`, which allows the suppression interval to be adjusted for a specific event source, affecting only events posted using that event source.

Unfortunately, the replacement`CGEventSourceSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval` does not work with `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition` movements.

Instead, use `CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition(true)` immediately after the warp:

```
CGPoint warpPoint = CGPointMake(42, 42);
CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(warpPoint);
CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition(true);
```

The documentation makes no mention of this behavior, but it appears to cancel the suppression interval after the warp.

Comment: CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition(true) doesn't remove the delay for me unfortunately

Answer (score 6):

I could get `CGEventSourceSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval` to work with `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition` the following way:

```
auto eventSourceRef = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);
CGEventSourceSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval(eventSourceRef, 0);
```

This works fine with `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition` (and is not deprecated), whereas `CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition(true)` was of no help for me.

Comment: This worked for me, whereas the suggestion above did not seem to work

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for CGSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval(), a method deprecated as of 10.6... it still works though in 10.7.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval

Comment: Yeah, I found that the other day, but it works perfectly, so I am going to give you the answer. Thanks for your time/effort.